# how to load socket.io without npm in node.exe?

Tags: node.js

How can I `include` a package like socket.io in node.exe(windows)?
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var socketio = require("./socketio/socket.io")
```

While my `package.json` file is stored in a folder called socketio where is in same folder as node.exe is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bundled socket.io via npm inside [node_modules](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/modules.html#loading_from_node_modules_Folders). You can download the [zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/314941/socketio.zip)(extract it first) and just use it thanks to node_modules.

You don't want to use NPM, but you do have a `package.json`(strange)? My advice would be to just install it via NPM. That's what package managers are for!

Comment: thank you! I switched to Linux now, but your answer seems to be correct. This is awesome!

Comment: @Mohsen haha you should switch to linux :P

Comment: @Mohsen, I'm trying to get npm to work on linux but have no luck getting examples to work. Did you use the standard curl method?