# how can I setup socket.io on winXP?

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-xp, socket.io

how can I setup socket.io on windowsXP?

http://socket.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this here: [how to load socket.io without npm in node.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758553/how-to-load-socket-io-without-npm-in-node-exe)

Download the socket.io library from the github: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io
You can download the zip version, extract it and name the folder with name `socket.io`
Put the folder into a folder with name `node_modules` in you project directory
Use `require` to use it in your code, `var io = require('socket.io');`